# Gremlin doesn't start up while connecting to cassandra

Tags: gremlin

I have my Titan 1.0.0 and cassandra 2.1.2 setup running fine in my linux. When i start my gremlin using,

```
./gremlin.sh ../conf/gremlin-server/gremlin-server-cassandra-es.yaml
```

I get the following error:

```
     \,,,/
     (o o)
-----oOOo-(3)-oOOo-----
plugin activated: aurelius.titan
plugin activated: tinkerpop.server
plugin activated: tinkerpop.utilities
SLF4J: Class path contains multiple SLF4J bindings.
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/home/ec2-user/titan/titan-1.0.0-  hadoop1/lib/slf4j-log4j12-1.7.5.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/home/ec2-user/titan/titan-1.0.0-hadoop1/lib/logback-classic-1.1.2.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]   
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#multiple_bindings for an explanation.
SLF4J: Actual binding is of type [org.slf4j.impl.Log4jLoggerFactory]
log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (org.apache.hadoop.security.Groups).
log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.
log4j:WARN See http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/faq.html#noconfig for more info.
plugin activated: tinkerpop.hadoop
plugin activated: tinkerpop.tinkergraph
==>10.253.11.125
==>8182
==>1
==>8
==>30000
==>30000
Exception in thread "main" groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: com for class: groovysh_evaluate
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.ScriptBytecodeAdapter.unwrap(ScriptBytecodeAdapter.java:51)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoGetPropertySite.getProperty(PogoGetPropertySite.java:49)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callGroovyObjectGetProperty(AbstractCallSite.java:304)
    at groovysh_evaluate.run(groovysh_evaluate:3)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.vmplugin.v7.IndyInterface.selectMethod(IndyInterface.java:215)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.tools.shell.Interpreter.evaluate(Interpreter.groovy:69)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.tools.shell.Groovysh.execute(Groovysh.groovy:185)
    at org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.console.Console.initializeShellWithScript(Console.groovy:290)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.vmplugin.v7.IndyInterface.selectMethod(IndyInterface.java:215)
    at org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.console.Console.<init>(Console.groovy:141)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.vmplugin.v7.IndyInterface.selectMethod(IndyInterface.java:215)
    at org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.console.Console.main(Console.groovy:303)
```

When i use,

```
./gremlin.sh
```

It runs but shows me with some error.

```
     \,,,/
     (o o)
-----oOOo-(3)-oOOo-----
plugin activated: aurelius.titan
plugin activated: tinkerpop.server
plugin activated: tinkerpop.utilities
SLF4J: Class path contains multiple SLF4J bindings.
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/home/ec2-user/titan/titan-1.0.0-hadoop1/lib/slf4j-log4j12-1.7.5.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/home/ec2-user/titan/titan-1.0.0-hadoop1/lib/logback-classic-1.1.2.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#multiple_bindings for an explanation.
SLF4J: Actual binding is of type [org.slf4j.impl.Log4jLoggerFactory]
log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (org.apache.hadoop.security.Groups).
log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.
log4j:WARN See http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/faq.html#noconfig for more info.
plugin activated: tinkerpop.hadoop
plugin activated: tinkerpop.tinkergraph
gremlin>
```

I want it to be connected to cassandra, so i want the first command to be working. I don't understand the issue there.

Comment: You're misusing the Gremlin console. `./gremlin.sh ../conf/gremlin-server/gremlin-server-cassandra-es.yaml` tries to execute the content of that file, but that won't work since it's a yaml file (see http://tinkerpop.incubator.apache.org/docs/3.0.1-incubating/#gremlin-console).

Answer (score 3):

You're starting the Gremlin console and telling it to load and execute the content of a `.yaml` file, which won't work since it's not a Groovy file. Running with `./gremlin.sh` should do the trick, however...

... you appear to be starting Titan and the Gremlin console from the `./bin` folder rather than the Titan root `./` folder. Go to Titan root folder and try starting both Titan and the Console with the following commands:

```
bin/titan.sh start
bin/gremlin.sh
```

If you didn't change any configuration file, this should work out of the box with the default Titan v1.0.0 install. To troubleshoot more, start Titan in verbose mode with:

```
bin/titan.sh start -v
```

To follow-up on your comment, it looks like you're getting started with Titan (and TinkerPop) and mixing some of the core concepts of each. You're currently trying to configure quite an advanced setup. I would recommend getting familiar with TinkerPop and TinkerGraph first (in-memory graph). Once you're comfortable with this, you can experiment with Titan, first with a single machine setup with Cassandra embedded (default setup), then with a remote Cassandra setup (what you're trying to achieve).

Comment: I'm trying to connect to cassandra which is the backend through gremlin. I have made few changes in the cassandra.yaml file [– seeds: "127.0.0.1" to – seeds: "192.168.14.129"
listen_address: 127.0.0.1 to listen_address: 192.168.14.129
rpc_address: 127.0.0.1 to rpc_address: 192.168.14.129]. I'm trying to start gremlin and i get the same error. Can you please share the steps where i can use cassandra as the backend. In your case, there is no backend used. I want to connect it with cassandra.

Comment: On creating a graph, using  g = TinkerGraphFactory.createTinkerGraph(), after running ./gremlin.sh,i get
groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: TinkerGraphFactory for class: groovysh_evaluate
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.ScriptBytecodeAdapter.unwrap(ScriptBytecodeAdapter.java:51)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoGetPropertySite.getProperty(PogoGetPropertySite.java:49)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callGroovyObjectGetProperty(AbstractCallSite.java:304)
        at groovysh_evaluate.run(groovysh_evaluate:3)

Comment: You're most likely looking for `graph = TitanFactory.open('conf/titan-cassandra-es.properties'); g = graph.traversal();`

Comment: Watch closely. You're typing `g = TinkerGraphFactory.createTinkerGraph(...)`. Titan uses `g = TitanFactory.open(...)`.

Comment: Still get this error, gremlin> g = TinkerFactory.open('/home/ec2-user/titan/titan-1.0.0-hadoop1/conf/titan-cassandra-es.properties')
groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: static org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.tinkergraph.structure.TinkerFactory.open() is applicable for argument types: (java.lang.String) values: [/home/ec2-user/titan/titan-1.0.0-hadoop1/conf/titan-cassandra-es.properties]
Possible solutions: grep(), use([Ljava.lang.Object;), grep(java.lang.Object), wait(), every(), dump()
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeStaticMissingMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1495)

Comment: Watch *more* closely please :). `Titan` is not the same thing as `TinkerGraph`.

Comment: Really sorry!!! I tried it, and this is what i get 'gremlin> graph = TitanFactory.open('conf/titan-cassandra-es.properties')
16:01:26 WARN  com.thinkaurelius.titan.graphdb.configuration.GraphDatabaseConfiguration  - Local setting index.search.elasticsearch.local-mode=true (Type: GLOBAL_OFFLINE) is overridden by globally managed value (false).  Use the ManagementSystem interface instead of the local configuration to control this setting.
Could not instantiate implementation: com.thinkaurelius.titan.diskstorage.es.ElasticSearchIndex
'

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, you try to start Gremlin server with Cassandra as storage backend(?) In this case try

```
$ path/to/gremlin-server.sh path/to/your/gremlin-server-cassandra-es.yaml
```

In another terminal you start the Gremlin client using

```
$ path/to/your/gremlin.sh
```

Then you can connect to the gremlin server:

```
 gremlin> :remote connect tinkerpop.server path/to/gremlin/conf/remote.yaml
```

As [jbmusso](https://stackoverflow.com/users/72351/jbmusso) already stated, in your first example you start the Gremlin client and pass it the config of the Gremlin server.

Comment: yes,correct!!! But, I had tried **path/to/gremlin-server.sh path/to/your/gremlin-server-cassandra-es.yaml** and got the above error. So i'm stuck there

Comment: Also tried **graph =TitanFactory.open('conf/titan-cassandra-es.properties')** after running **./gremlin.sh** that leads to,`gremlin> graph = TitanFactory.open('conf/titan-cassandra-es.properties')16:01:26WARNcom.thinkaurelius.titan.graphdb.configuration.GraphDatabaseConfiguration - Local setting index.search.elasticsearch.local-mode=true (Type: GLOBAL_OFFLINE) is overridden by globally managed value (false).Use the ManagementSystem interface instead of the local configuration to control this setting.Could not instantiate implementation:com.thinkaurelius.titan.diskstorage.es.ElasticSearchIndex`

Comment: You might have to start all over from scratch. Shutdown Titan (`bin/titan.sh stop`), then remove data (`rm -rf db`, assuming you're ok to permanently delete everything) then start Titan again (`bin/titan.sh start`), then launch the console (`bin/gremin.sh`). I still strongly suggest that you get yourself more familiar with TinkerPop before using Titan.

Comment: I have setup my cassandra and titan running. And gremlin also works fine. I have connected gremlin to cassandra using,

`gremlin>conf=new BaseConfiguration();
gremlin>conf.setProperty('storage.backend','cassandra');
gremlin>conf.setProperty('storage.hostname', '192.168.14.129');
gremlin>conf.setProperty('storage.keyspace','test');
gremlin>g=TitanFactory.open(conf);`
And i have created a vertex,

`gremlin> v1 = g.addVertex(label,"person","f_name","Anna");
==>v[8424]`
How do i check if this data is entered into cassandra in test keyspace(already in cassandra)?

Comment: One minor detail: better name your TitanGraph `graph` instead of `g`. Most examples and tutorials use `g` as notation for the traversal. Naming your graph `g` may lead to confusion later on. I'm not sure whether I understand your question: Do you want to retrieve the just added vertex?

Comment: Yes!! I want to know if that vertex is moved to cassandra.