# Check successful loading of data into cassandra by gremlin

Tags: gremlin

I have setup my cassandra and titan running. And gremlin also works fine. I have connected gremlin to cassandra using,

```
gremlin>conf=new BaseConfiguration();
gremlin>conf.setProperty('storage.backend','cassandra');
gremlin>conf.setProperty('storage.hostname', '192.168.14.129');
gremlin>conf.setProperty('storage.keyspace','test');
gremlin>g=TitanFactory.open(conf);
```

And i have created a vertex,

```
gremlin> v1 = g.addVertex(label,"person","f_name","Anna");
==>v[8424]
```

How do i check if this data is entered into cassandra in test keyspace(already in cassandra)?

Answer (score 1):

TinkerPop v3.x distinguishes between a Graph and a TraversalSource.

You should be doing the following only once:

```
graph = TitanFactory.open(conf)
g = graph.traversal()
```

Then execute all your traversals with:

```
g.V().some(...).gremlin(...).steps(...)
```

To find a Vertex by its id in Titan, you may have to cast the id to a Long. Assuming a Vertex with id `8424l`, you can do:

```
g.V(8424l) // returns a traversal
g.V(8424l).next() // returns that vertex
```

You shouldn't be calling `graph.traversal()` more than once, as you get a performance hit every time. In the default Titan v1.0.0 setup, notice how the traversal initialization is done when starting Gremlin server (see `conf/gremlin-server/gremlin-server.yaml` which executes the `scripts/empty-sample.groovy` file).

Answer (score 0):

According to your comment underneath [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37464192/6313877) you want to retrieve the just added vertex. Please refer to the Tinkerpop [reference](http://tinkerpop.apache.org/docs/3.2.0-incubating/reference/). Using your `g` as notation for the graph it's simple as

```
gremlin> g.traversal().V(8424)
```

For getting the properties of the vertex read `valueMap` step in the reference. For obtaining the vertex not by its Id, but by its properties read `has` step. Be aware that I linked to the reference for Tinkerpop 3.2.0. You might chose a different version of that document to meet your very version of the stack.